# Is it possible to have an ATX and a mini ITX boards running under one (ATX) PSU?

Tags: power-supply, atx, mini-itx

Specifically - are there any ATX PSU's with double 24 pins, or some kind of adapters that would make it possible?

Comment: I've never seen anything like this, and I really can't think of any reason why it's be manufactured.  can you maybe explain exactly what your goal is here?  There may be another alternative that doesn't require something so specific.

Comment: I'm a cheapskate - that's all. Kinda hurts to pay as much for a mini ITX PSU as for the mainboard itself. Also, I'm asking out of pure curiosity.

Comment: I'm really curious how on earth one would cable such a beast.  Two machines in a single chassis?  Or would this just be loose on a workbench?

Comment: Even if you can find a PSU that support two mobo, how are you going to connect keyboard, mouse, monitor (...). It is just too much to do. Come on, if you can afford a mini ITX mobo, a mini ITX case will not bankrupt you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen a device as you describe, and would guess it does not exist. I believe it would be difficult to produce it and still live up to (among other things) industry safety standards. I could be wrong.

However, it would be simple to create one yourself. Just get an extra 24-pin connector with as long wires as possible from somewhere and connect it in parallel to the one already on the PSU. You can use something like [these](http://www.clasohlson.no/Archive/Images/Products/Hi/25-358.jpg) to make the connections.

Just make a note not to connect the "power on" wire to more than one of the connectors, or you might get surprises. I won't attempt to explain which one it is in text, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Power_supply) in stead. They list it as pin 16.

Comment: if playing this game then a good idea to test the current with a multimeter. also bear in mind you may need to connect the multimeter in series to test the current.  see if the current is less than it would normally be, i'm not an electronics geek but it may be less current goes to each board.

Comment: Well, as you say, measuring (direct) currents requires a serial connection, which in this case is highly impractical. The common solution to that would be to measure the potential differences at the consumer end (close to or on the mainboards). This approach has the added advantage that the optimal values are given in the ATX spec so you won't have to guess if what you measure is correct.